# prefetch db rows using the python peewee orm

Tags: python, prefetch, peewee

I want to use the python peewee prefetch functionality.

I have three tables: `A`, `B`, and `C`.

`B` has a foreign key in its table to `A`, and table `C` has a foreign key to `B`.

I want to select all the rows in `B`, while also prefetching the rows in `C` that belong to those in `B`. However, I also want to grab the rows in `A` that `B` belongs to so I don't launch new queries every time I try accessing that property from the results.

This is the code I have currently:

```
b_query = B.select(B, A).join(A).where(B.user_id == user_id)
c_query = C.select()

prefetch(b_query, c_query)
```

However, this code fails with the error: `OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`

When I change the code to this it works:

```
b_query = B.select().join(A).where(B.user_id == user_id)
c_query = C.select()
```

But, since I am no longer selecting `A` in `b_query`, I believe every time I access `b.a` it will launch a new query, which I am trying to avoid. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I did some more digging into this, and it seems that trying to do it the way I initially proposed might be impossible. The successful mechanism results in this query as one of the two queries resulting from the `prefetch`:

`SELECT C.* from C WHERE C.B_id IN (SELECT B.id FROM B WHERE B.user_id == <user_id>)`

Trying to add `A` into the `select` for `b_query` results in the following query:

`SELECT C.* from C WHERE C.B_id IN (SELECT B.*, A.* WHERE B.user_id == <user_id>)`

Obviously this won't work.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/324

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the result of a bug in the prefetch function. I opened an issue on peewee's issue tracker and the bug is fixed in master (https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/324). Commit `e9a38d24b`.

Comment: Sure thing -- if you think you find a bug don't hesitate to open an issue on github.